# Having issues with changing a div background image?

Tags: html, css

i'm having issues here with my `onmouseover`event. What i'm trying to do is when the mouse is over the div it changes the background to a different image but when it's not over it it goes back to it's old image. Here's the code i'm using; if anyone can clear this up for me it would be very appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="contentDiv">
        <div id="ringDiv">
            <div id="ringTL" onmouseover="ringTL.className='ringOverTL'">
            </div>
            <div id="ringTR">
            </div>
            <div id="ringBL">
            </div>
            <div id="ringBR">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#contentDiv{
    width:80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;  
}
#ringDiv{
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width:410px;
    height:410px;
}
#ringTL {
    float:left;
    width:205px;
    height:205px;
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/BackRing/TL.png);
}

#ringTR {
    float:right;
    width:205px;
    height:205px;
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/BackRing/TR.png);
}

#ringBL {
    float:left;
    width:205px;
    height:205px;
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/BackRing/BL.png);
}

#ringBR {
    float:right;
    width:205px;
    height:205px;
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/BackRing/BR.png);
}

.ringOverTL{
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/FrontRing/TL.png);
}

.ringOverTR{
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/FrontRing/TR.png);
}

.ringOverBL{
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/FrontRing/BL.png);
}

.ringOverBR{
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/FrontRing/BR.png);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a normal class with one image and a hover class with the other right in your CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an easier way to do this is to use `:hover`.

Try something like this:

```
<body>
<div id="contentDiv">
    <div id="ringDiv">
        <div id="ringTL">
        </div>
        <div id="ringTR">
        </div>
        <div id="ringBL">
        </div>
        <div id="ringBR">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#ringTL {
  float:left;
  width:205px;
  height:205px;
  background-image:url(../IMAGES/BackRing/TL.png);
}

#ringTL:hover {
  background-image:url(..<your-other-photo>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the css `hover` selector?

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="contentDiv">
        <div id="ringDiv">
            <div id="ringTL">
            </div>
            <div id="ringTR">
            </div>
            <div id="ringBL">
            </div>
            <div id="ringBR">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#contentDiv{
    width:80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;  
}
#ringDiv{
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width:410px;
    height:410px;
}
#ringTL {
    float:left;
    width:205px;
    height:205px;
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/BackRing/TL.png);
}

#ringTR {
    float:right;
    width:205px;
    height:205px;
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/BackRing/TR.png);
}

#ringBL {
    float:left;
    width:205px;
    height:205px;
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/BackRing/BL.png);
}

#ringBR {
    float:right;
    width:205px;
    height:205px;
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/BackRing/BR.png);
}

#ringTL:hover {
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/FrontRing/TL.png);
}

.ringOverTR{
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/FrontRing/TR.png);
}

.ringOverBL{
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/FrontRing/BL.png);
}

.ringOverBR{
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/FrontRing/BR.png);
}
```